# Compatibility view makes my page go wrong?

Tags: html, css

a website for my client "jordanzad.com" the main page design gets broken when viewing in compatibility view?

Comment: Don't you wish IE didn't exist and you didn't have to deal with "compatability anything" and just code normally for normal, standard browsers?

Comment: Oh yes ! i wish IE never existed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, force IE8 mode by placing this in between your `<head></head>`

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="X-UA-Compatible" CONTENT="IE=100" /> <!-- IE8 mode -->
```

or tinker with it for I87 compatibility CSS styles etc to get it right.  I just force to IE8 mode, I hate compatibility mode.